# How can I backup Windows 7 with programs and files?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, reinstall

Is there any way that I can reinstall Windows 7 and put all my programs and files back on the system without reinstalling programs one-by-one, like a Mac?

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 includes an image-based backup system which will backup your drives 'as-is', so you can restore them as such, in case of system failure.

It's called [Windows Backup and Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore). Specifically the "System image backup" feature.

You can read more on the FAQ, under "[What backup tools does Windows provide?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/Back-up-and-restore-frequently-asked-questions)":

> Windows Backup provides you with the ability to create a system image, which is an exact image of a drive. A system image includes Windows and your system settings, programs, and files. You can use a system image to restore the contents of your computer if your hard drive or computer ever stops working. When you restore your computer from a system image, it is a complete restoration; you can't choose individual items to restore, and all of your current programs, system settings, and files are replaced. Although this type of backup includes your personal files, we recommend that you back up your files regularly using Windows Backup so that you can restore individual files and folders as needed. When you set up scheduled file backup, you can choose whether you want to include a system image. This system image only includes the drives required for Windows to run. You can manually create a system image if you want to include additional data drives.

Comment: I would like to do fresh install and put al programs back without reinstall.

Comment: That's exactly what it's for.  Just ensure you tell it to make an 'image backup' during use. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs to be a bit more specific. If your asking about doing a full re-install with the system exactly the way it is now, then techie007 is right, you need an imaging type backup. There are many programs that will do that for you. If you want to do a baremetal fresh install where you only care about the programs, not your original data etc.. There are programs that can help reduce the work, but the programs will still be re-installed, tese programs just handle the download and install for you. Something like [Ninite](http://ninite.com/) will install a lot of the free/open programs that are typically installed now with a checkbox interface on the web to pick what you want.

Comment: thanks, i think there is no way to copy and paste programs in windows like mac.

Comment: "i think there is no way to copy and paste programs in windows like mac", correct since Windows uses the registry it is quite messy to attempt transfer of programs without a re-install of the program.