# Backup and restore Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incremental image backup for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/226766/incremental-image-backup-for-windows-7)

Sometimes it is necessary to reinstall windows and when I do that I have to install all my software and updates after the re-installation. This is a huge pain and takes too much time. I was wondering if there is a backup-restore system with which I can backup and restore my windows without harming other drive data.

Comment: Depending on your version of Windows 7, Image-type backups are built in. What have you actually tried already?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incremental image backup for Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/226766/incremental-image-backup-for-windows-7) and/or [Windows backup by Imaging](http://superuser.com/questions/7739/windows-backup-by-imaging) and.or [How can I backup Windows 7 with programs and files?](http://superuser.com/questions/332197/how-can-i-backup-windows-7-with-programs-and-files)

Comment: Tried ImageX, Windows in-built imaging utility, take an image, blow it onto any HDD you wish

Answer (score 2):

I think [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) might meet your requirements. You would be able to clone your HD and restore from that cloned image at any point in the future. This just requires a dedicated backup drive. The cloned image will be a nearly exact copy of your current HD state.

However note that this would simply restore your system to an earlier configuration, not the same as reinstalling your operating system and then restoring your system preferences/applications.

There are also a number of other tools that can be used to create a cloned image of your system.